# Setting mouse acceleration using xset and xinput

Tags: linux, mouse

I am having trouble sorting out how the different commands for setting mouse acceleration relate to each other.

I will post the different settings that I have set by gathering information from different sources.

First of I have set the following setting in my.xsessionrc

```
xset m 8/8 0
```

I got this from a reddit post to get replicable mouse settings over different installations. What I don't see about this is why you would set it to 8/8 instead of just xset 1 0.

The other option I have been messing with is to set the "Device Accel Profile" to -1. I have been told that this will disable mouse acceleration altogether.

```
xinput set-prop 10 269 -1
```

In the above command the 10 is my mouse-id and 269 is the property-id.

Also in the /etc/modules file I have added the lines

```
-r usbhid
usbhid mousepoll=1
```

This should set my mouse polling frequency to 1000hz. For other rates one can consult the table on this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_polling_rate).

Now for the confusion part. Will disabling the mouse acceleration with the xinput command also make the "xset m" command useless since it is working with the acceleration?

I have also seen posts where recommendations have been given to alter the "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" option to alter the mouse speed. Setting the "Device Accel Profile" to -1 also disables this doesn't it?